# Spring Web MVC Json - jackson key/name for array of objects (named array)

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

How do I get a json, containing java objects, but with a key as identifier of the array?
I have the following in Spring mvc 4.x. I use the Jackson library to marshal the objects to json.

```
@RequestMapping(value="dogs")
    public List<Dog> getDogs(){
        List<Dog> list_dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
        list_dogs.add(new Dog("dog1",1));
        list_dogs.add(new Dog("dog2",2));
        return list_dogs;   
    }
```

I get the following response: `[{"name":"dog1","age":1},{"name":"dog2","age":2}]`

I would like to have it like the following:

```
{
    "array": [{
        "name": "dog1",
        "age": 1
    }, {
        "name": "dog2",
        "age": 2
    }]
}
```

How do I provide the name for the array?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, use a Map instead of only a List.

```
@RequestMapping(value="dogs")
public Map<String, List<Dog>> getDogs(){
    Map<String, List<Dog>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Dog>>();
    List<Dog> list_dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    list_dogs.add(new Dog("dog1",1));
    list_dogs.add(new Dog("dog2",2));
    map.put("myArray", list_dogs);
    //return list_dogs; [{"name":"dog1","age":1},{"name":"dog2","age":2}]
    return map;     //{"myArray":[{"name":"dog1","age":1},{"name":"dog2","age":2}]}
}

{"myArray":[{"name":"dog1","age":1},{"name":"dog2","age":2}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response you are expecting is a json object and not a json array.
So create a json object / map with the required key

```
@RequestMapping(value="dogs")
public Map<String, List<Dog>> getDogs(){
    List<Dog> list_dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    list_dogs.add(new Dog("dog1",1));
    list_dogs.add(new Dog("dog2",2));
    Map<String, List<Dog>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("array", list_dogs);
    return map;   
}
```